# Coding practice - using abstract or a private constructor

Tags: c#, access-modifiers

I have a question about coding practice. I want to create a class which can't be initialized. I believe I have 3 options:

- Abstract modifier
- Static modifier
- Private constructor

I don't want to create a static class simply because of having to name all of my properties and methods 'static' - it looks messy (and I can't use the 'this' keyword).

According to the MSDN:

> Use the abstract modifier in a class declaration to indicate that a
>   class is intended only to be a base class of other classes.

**Edit** Nothing will inherit form this class.

However, it would be a solution (but it seems wrong to me to use it in this situation).

Or, I can make a private constructor so the class cannot be initialized.

If it helps the reason for why is this: The class is responsible for starting off a work flow process. It doesn't need to be initialized since nothing is returned - it just needs to be 'started'.

Demo code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WorkFlow wf = new WorkFlow(); // this will error which is fine!
        ComplexObject co = new ComplexObject();
        WorkFlow.Begin(co);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class WorkFlow 
{
    private WorkFlow()
    {
        //private to prevent initialization but this feels wrong! 
    }

    public static void Begin(ComplexObject co)
    {
        //code to begin the workflow
    }
}
```

Comment: [Implementing Singleton in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx) or [J.Skeet: Implementing the Singleton Pattern in C#](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx).

Comment: I don't believe this is a singleton as I don't want a single instance running

Comment: @DaveRook: I'm not quite sure where you want to go by making the class abstract. If it has instance methods and/or properties (and this it does, I figure from your statement that you don't want to declare all of the properties and methods as static), there will be no way to ever invoke or access any of these instance methods or properties if your class is abstract and nothing derives from it. Your choice is: Either you do not want any instance of the class, then you have to declare any members static. Or you do want to have one instance of your class, then you want a singleton.

Comment: @DaveRook if you want more than one instance running, who would create the other instances (and how)? Note that with an abstract constructor you would not be able to create new instances at all (you would need to subclass), with a private constructor only a method of the class itself would be able to create and return new instances of the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about doing just what you have done but using your Begin method as a factory to create your workflow.

```
var workflow = Workflow.Begin(complexObject); 

public class WorkFlow  
{ 
    private WorkFlow() 
    { 
        //private to prevent initialization but this feels wrong!  
    } 

    public static WorkFlow Begin(ComplexObject co) 
    { 
        return new Workflow(co);
    } 
}
```

Comment: I'm going to ask a daft question I'm sure - but how would this work when the Begin method returns void?

Comment: I am suggesting that you change that to return a new instance of Workflow.  i.e. factory method

Comment: OK, thank you for clearing that up. The point is, there is nothing to create so I don't think the factory pattern will work.

Comment: @Dave,  from the code sample you supplied above it's very difficult to see how you intend using your workflow class.  I would feel a little uncomfortable with a class that has only one static method on it.  How does a workflow end? What are the responsibilities of the workflow class?

Comment: Good question - At the moment, I am thinking my class is literally just method calls to various actions which the workflow must call. However, this approach makes me feel like I'm programming in Pascal again instead of C# - It feels wrong, hence why I'm looking for a design pattern to steer me in the right direction.

Comment: Have a look at the template method pattern.  It could also be an option. See : http://www.oodesign.com/template-method-pattern.html (I know the code here is Java, but the principle is the same).  And for a .net example http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternTemplate.aspx

Answer (score 4):

> I want to create a class which can't be initialized.

That leaves the possible usages: static or base-class only.

If your class is going to be derived from, use `abstract`. A private/protected constructor would be a hack in this situation.

Your sample code looks more like a `static` class. With Singleton as alternative.

Comment: I agree - so, would you say you're against the private constructor?

Comment: A private ctor is usually part of a Singleton. But as alternative to 'abstract' it makes no sense.

Answer (score 3):

Good practice: Private constructor (at least is what the [GOF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) book recommends when using the [Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) pattern, for example). I'll suggest you to use abstract if it's a base class (that's what it's name suggest).

Answer (score 2):

If the class is strictly being used as a base class, it would have to be `abstract` for me.

Based on your update I would go for a static class & method e.g.

```
WorkFlow.Begin(co);
```

However, since you don't want to do this I think it only leaves you with one option...private constructor.

Comment: From your answer, I assume you would rather use static than a private constructor?

Comment: @DaveRook Well based on the sample code provided, I don't really see any need for the class to be instantiated *at all*. Does your WF class hold any sort of state?

Comment: No, it takes the ComplexObject and gets persisted into several databases and logged in several locations.

Comment: Well if your class carries no state, then it should be `static` IMO.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you would need a singleton.

More reference here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650849.aspx

if you dont like the ideea, well an abstract class would be best suited because as you said you dont want to instantiate it, and lets not forget that the abstract class does just that, so why try and use a private constructor.

Comment: So, you feel in this case, abstract is better than a private constructor?

Comment: yes, updated my answer. my theory is that if you already have something defined for this case, then using a private constructor would just look like a workaround, that has no reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want to create a static class simply because of having to name
>   all of my properties and methods 'static' - it looks messy (and I
>   can't use the 'this' keyword).

Well, either you make ctor `private` or make a class `static`, the only way caller can access methods and properties of your class (if the caller is not derived one) is via `public static` members.

Having `private ctor` give you more flexibility in inheritance chain, but doesn't help much in "avoid static members" scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I will prefer private constructor ie its identical to Singleton pattern

[Info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

[Coding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx)

Private constructors seems to be good approach for your requirement. Abstracts are good too but private constructor is handy than abstract. But if you would like to extend its information then its probably good idea to use abstract.

Answer (score 1):

If the class needs to be "started" it needs to be initialized (unless all you're going to use are static methods).
Abstract classes are used to leave some (or all) of the implementation to subclasses, and by your description - not suitable for you.
"Static classes" - no special gain here I guess (in your case).
Private constructors - used to limit who can instantiate the class.
Not sure that any of these matches your design, but I guess you really want a singleton - look it up, this is the most common and basic design pattern.
BTW - I use singletons only as a last resort, usually when the class controls some kind of non shared resource.